# new to recursion, can't find solution

Tags: python, recursion

I'm supposed to get those results, the first two strings are the s1 and s2 and the third one is the result i should get.
The first code is the one i wrote and the second one is the teacher's.

```py
“Maria” e “Norma”: Mnao |
“Mai” e “Nor”: Mnaoir   |
“Maria” e “Noa”:False   |
“Mar” e “Noa”: MNaora   |
“Mar” e “Noar”: False
```

```py
def strin(s1,s2):
    count_n(s1,s2)
    if len(s1)==len(s2) or s1[n]==s2[n]:
        if s1[0]==s2[0]:
            return ""
        else:
            return s1[0]+s2[0]+strin(s1[1:],s2[1:])
    else:
        return False



def count_n(s1,s2):
    global n
    n=0
    if len(s1)==len(s2) and (len(s1)>0 or len(s2)>0):
        if s1[0]==s2[0]:
            return n
        else:
            return (n+1) and count_n(s1[1:],s2[1:])
    else:
        return n
```

teacher's answer

def intercala( s1,s2):

```
if s1=='' and s2 == '':
     return ''
if s1=='' or s2 =='':
    return  False
if s1[0] == s2[0]:
    return ''

resp= intercala(s1[1:], s2[1:])
if resp != False:
    return s1[0]+s2[0]+resp
else:
    return resp
```

def intercala2(s1,s2):

```
if s1=='' and s2 == '':
     return ''
if s1=='' or s2 =='':
    return False
if s1[-1] == s2[-1]:
    return intercala2(s1[0:-1],s2[0:-1])

resp= intercala(s1[0:-1], s2[0:-1])
if resp != False:
    return resp + s1[-1]+s2[-1]
else:
    return resp
```

Comment: What is `return (n+1) and count_n(...)` supposed to do? Since `n` starts at 0, `n+1` will always be True so the expression will short-circuit and the recursion will never be called.

Comment: Can you try to distill a specific technical question out of this? If you figure out exactly what assumption your code is based on that doesn't hold, for instance, that allows a more specific and precise question. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) -- in short, we expect homework questions to comply to the same quality standards as any other question on the site; those standards include specificity, and call for providing a [mcve] -- code that can be directly copied-and-pasted by someone who wants to reproduce or test their answer.

Comment: Ok. I have to return interchangeable caracthers from both strings if they have the same lengh or  have a letter in common in the same position. if not the code should return False. Sorry if i wasn't so clear the teacher's question is kind confusing as well. Iwill post his answer too

Comment: This looked liked fun, heres a 1 liner, although it doesn't use recursion: `"".join(map("".join,zip(str1[:([a[0] == a[1] for a in zip(str1,str2)]+[True]).index(True)],str2[:([a[0] == a[1] for a in zip(str1,str2)]+[True]).index(True)]))) if len(str1) == len(str2) else False`

Answer (score 0):

hey guys i found a answer, thanks for the help

```
def recur(s1,s2):
if len(s1)==len(s2):
    if s1[0]==s2[0]:
        return ""
    if len(s1)==1 or len(s2)==1:
        return s1[0]+s2[0]
    else:
        return s1[0]+s2[0]+recur(s1[1:],s2[1:])
else:
    return False
```